# null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.HashMap in my application

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
 fun refreshUsers() {
    val userData = UserData(this)
   databaseRef!!.child("User").child(userData.loadPhoneNumber()).child("Finders")
            .addValueEventListener(object :
            ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {

            val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>

           listOfContact.clear()
            if (td==null){
                listOfContact.add(UserContact("NO_USERS","nothing"))
                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                return
            }
            for (key in td.keys){
                val name = listOfContacts[key]
                listOfContact.add(UserContact(name.toString(),key))
            }
            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

i have a problem in hashmap and that's the error:

kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.HashMap
                      at com.example.userandro.phonetracker.MainActivity$refreshUsers$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.kt:87)

i need help please

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when attempting to cast `null` to a [non-null type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types). This is a runtime error in Kotlin. In the line below, `value` is `null`, however the specified type isn't nullable.

```
val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>
```

If the intention is for the variable to be nullable, you can use `as?` (with a question mark) the ["safe" (nullable) cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) instead. In case of failure, the result will be `null` rather than an exception.

```
val td = dataSnapshot!!.value as? HashMap<String,Any>
```

Comment: Its work but after that i have error in other fuction

Comment: can u give me ur email account please i need you ^_^ #jspcal